# How to install tensorflow-transform on anaconda?

Tags: anaconda, conda, tensorflow-transform

We can install tensorflow-transform using pip but how do I install it using Conda?

I have tried using `conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-transform` and all its variants without result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A search of Anaconda Cloud](https://anaconda.org/search?q=tensorflow-transform) shows that `tensorflow-transform` is not available through any channels on any platform. Moreover, [the recommended way to install the package is to use PyPI](https://github.com/tensorflow/transform#installation).  However, one can still install the package into a specific Conda env by first activating the env:

```
conda activate your_env
pip install tensorflow-transform
```

Comment: Thank you. 
tensorflow-transform works for python 2.x (7<=x<10) for anyone looking to install it

Comment: the latest release of tensorflow transform 0.13 supports Python 3.5. see pypi: https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-transform/